# how do i change frame size dimension in the properties?

Tags: anylogic

i do not know why i cannot change the height and and wight in the frame properties.Any suggestion?
[image: Frame Properties]

Comment: this is an older version of anylogic... which one is it?

Comment: the version is 7.0.2. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Felipe said, it depends on the version.

In AnyLogic 8, You can change it directly as below:
[image]

In older versions, you change it in the experiment settings. Click on the experiment you want to run and amend as below:
[image]

Comment: In both AnyLogic 8 and 7 you can change it on the canvas - but only from the Simulation Object (not main)